# Trying to redirect in ObjectDataSource OnUpdated EventHandler

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

When I use OnUpdated in my ObjectDataSource I get

> No overload for 'OnUpdated' matches delegate >'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceStatusEventHandler'

I find nothing on web to help even though I find OnUpdated in Declaritive Syntax at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.aspx

I just want to redirect when form is updated.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
DataObjectTypeName="ProfileWrapper" SelectMethod="GetData" 
TypeName="ProfileDataSource" UpdateMethod="UpdateData"
OnUpdated="Redirect_OnUpdated">
```

```
   protected virtual void Redirect_OnUpdated(object source, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("ShoppingCart.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.updated.aspx):

Handle the Updated event to examine the values of a return value or output parameters, or to determine whether an exception was thrown after an Update operation has completed. The return value, output parameters, and exception handling properties are available from the **ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs** object that is associated with the event.

Your method signature is wrong: you used ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs.

Comment: Good eye! And fast also. Thank you so very much! Works fine now.